# How to stop the setInterval using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown where I can select the time for the `setInterval`.

test.php:

```
 <select id="proc_id" class="multiselect custom processselect" name="proc_id" style="display: none;">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
```

If select "0" stop the executing the `setinterval` and 1 for 1 sec and 2 for 2 sec.

test.js

```
var set_time = 0;
var interval;

$('#proc_id').change(function() {
    set_time = $('#proc_id :selected').val();
    // alert((set_time));
    if(parseInt(set_time) > 0) {
        set_time= set_time * 1000;
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            getFileProcessList(start_date);
            getResultInfoList(start_date); 
        }, set_time);
    } 
    else {
        alert('bye');
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
});
```

If I selected the `0`, it not clearing the interval. Please can anyone help how to stop the `setInterval` function?

Comment: is it going in `else` part?

Comment: Ya when i select 0 it is going to else and alerting but setInterval function not stopping still executing

Comment: It's working proeprly. You can check this link: https://jsfiddle.net/3j9qbngb/

Comment: Your code worked for me, the interval stopped after alert(bye).

Comment: are those `alert()`s causing an issue? if you set it to 1 and the `alert()` appears and then you wait 30s before closing the alert it looks as though it's "queuing" the alerts. If you change you code so that it changes the background color of an element rather alerting does it work better?

Comment: Trung's answer below looks good. I never noticed at first but the problem arises when you select 1, wait, select 2, wait, select 0. When it creates the interval for "2" it doesn't clear the interval for "1".

Comment: Ya wat dave told it is happening for me.It is not clearing when we select 1 then 2 then 0 or 1 then 2 then 0 cases.

Answer (score 1):

You should clear the previous interval before start the new one. Your code should be updated like this

```
    var set_time = 0;
    var interval = 0;
    $('#proc_id').change(function(){
        set_time=$('#proc_id :selected').val();
        if(parseInt(set_time) > 0) {

            set_time= set_time * 1000;
            if (interval != 0) {
              // clear previous interval before start the new one
              clearInterval(interval);
            }
            interval = setInterval(function() {
                getFileProcessList(start_date);
                getResultInfoList(start_date);
            }, set_time);
        } 
        else {
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = 0;
        }
    });
```

I've created a sample at this link https://jsfiddle.net/mhL907eo/1/, please check.